# WordPress doesn't remember my custom rewrite rule

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have the following code:

```
function b09_custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
      'utils/([^/]+)/?',
      'index.php?utils=$matches[1]',
      'top'
    );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'b09_custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);

function b09_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
    array_push( $query_vars, 'utils' );
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'b09_query_vars' );

function b09_template_redirect(){
    global $wp_query;

    $utils_page = get_query_var("utils");

    var_dump( $utils_page );

    if( $utils_page ):
        // custom function
        exit();
    endif;
}
add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'b09_template_redirect' );
```

Everything works as expected, but as soon as I remove the line `flush_rewrite_rules()`, WordPress is disabling the rule on the next reload.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue. It is probably that your problem is any other piece of code in your site.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @cybmeta for your hint. I searched my theme and found an other `flush_rewrite_rules(true);` on the init hook. I removed this and now the rule is being remembered.

Seemingly, calling the function twice is breaking something. Doesn't really make sense to me, but it works now, so whatever :)

Comment: Having `flush_rewrite_rules` in `init` is a bad idea and will probably slow down your site.  You only need to call it once, preferably during the activation of a plugin.

Comment: You are right, but still it should not break the rewrite rules if called twice.

Comment: But if its in init its called every time you go to tge site

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's why I removed it all together.